# create a uiview object from cgrect

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a custom table view cell where i create 3 images with:

```
[aUIImage drawInRect:someCGRect];
```

Is there a way I can create 3 UIView objects from these images, so I can access them in my touchesBegan method to find which image was touched?  Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way would be using the UIButton instead the UIView. You just need to specify the image property and the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for each.